# OracleDependency

Tags: asp.net, oracle

Quiero hacer una aplicacion que tenga notificaciones push, utilizando OracleDependency, sigo las instrucciones de la documentación.

Ejecuto las siguientes ordenes:

```
grant change notification to SN_Hospitales;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION TO SN_Hospitales;
```

y tengo el codigo siguiente:

```
 var Entidad= "sn_hospitales.entidad_dependency";
        var login = "DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION = " +
                    " (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.54.170) 
(PORT = 1521)) " +
                    " (CONNECT_DATA = " +
                    " (SERVER = DEDICATED) " +
                    " (SERVICE_NAME = SERUD) " +
                    " ))   ; USER ID=SN_Hospitales;PASSWORD=XXXXXX";



        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(login);
        con.Open();
        OracleDependency dependency = new OracleDependency();
        OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        string sql = "select nombre from " + Entidad;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);
        dependency.AddCommandDependency(cmd);
        cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;
        cmd.AddRowid = true;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Pero no funciona, alguien puede ayudarme si me dejo algo o se tiene que hacer algo en el Oracle?

gracias